# Web Scraping with R inside an iframe

Tags: r, web-scraping, iframe, rvest

I'm trying to extract a list of clinic names via web scraping through a website but realise the webpage contains several iframes. This is my first time doing web scraping and I have been spending hours doing research for the solution but to no avail.

This is my current code so far:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

healthhub.url <- "https://www.healthhub.sg/directory/clinics-and-polyclinics/"
iframe_src <- html_session(healthhub.url) %>%
  html_node("iframe") %>%
  html_attr("src")

iframe_url <- str_c(healthhub.url,iframe_src)

html_session(iframe_url) %>%
    html_nodes(".app_ment") %>%
    html_text()
```

It didn't work, of course, or I wouldn't have to ask help from the experts.

I've tried checking for **iframe_url** and it only shows one result, which contradicts with my inspection using view_page_source. The resulted **iframe_url** is not the one in which the clinic names are embedded in. In fact, it's the second one which didn't show up.

I have no idea what and where went wrong. Would really appreciate helps from anyone. Thanks!

Edit: To clarify, I was able to extract the first page list, but when I was trying to extract the subsequent pages of information, the url didn't change, hence I suspect they were embedded in the iframes.

Comment: Looks like ASPX page does postback and that __EVENTTARGET triggers the next batch of results

Comment: They sound alien to me. Any relevant articles about those terms that I could read would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scrape the names and addresses of the clinics in the directory using HTML nodes only, as I've done on the code that follows:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

healthhub.url <- "https://www.healthhub.sg/directory/clinics-and-polyclinics/"

clinic_dets <- html_session(healthhub.url) %>%
    html_nodes(".app_ment") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_extract(., "[^\\r\\n].*") %>%
    trimws()

clinic_address <- html_session(healthhub.url) %>%
    html_nodes(".add_sign") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_extract(., "[^\\r\\n].*") %>%
    trimws()

clinic_name <- ""

for (clinic_idx in (1:length(clinic_dets))) {
    clinic_name[clinic_idx] <- sub(clinic_address[clinic_idx], '', clinic_dets[clinic_idx])
}

clinic_name <- trimws(clinic_name)

df <- data.frame(clinic_name, clinic_address)
```

Now the tricky part is to navigate across the results pages, which is done via a Javascript request. You can achieve this using `Selenium` to open an instance of a browser, simulate the navigation, and extract the data from there, as I've done on the code below:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(RSelenium)

scrape_clinics_data <- function(page_html){
    #'
    #'@description Retrieves clinics names and addresses from directory on
    #'main source URL.
    #'
    #' Parameters:
    #'@param page_html (XML): An XML document containing the webpages HTML code.
    #'
    #' Returns:
    #'@return page_df (data.frame): i x 2 data.frame with columns
    #'clinic_name (chr) and clinic_address (chr), where i equals the number of
    #'clinics retrieved from the given page.
    #'
    #'@importFrom rvest, stringr
    #'
    clinic_dets <- page %>%
        html_nodes(".app_ment") %>%
        html_text() %>%
        str_extract(., "[^\\r\\n].*") %>%
        trimws()

    clinic_address <- page %>%
        html_nodes(".add_sign") %>%
        html_text() %>%
        str_extract(., "[^\\r\\n].*") %>%
        trimws()

    clinic_name <- ""

    for (clinic_idx in (1:length(clinic_dets))) {
        clinic_name[clinic_idx] <- sub(clinic_address[clinic_idx], '', clinic_dets[clinic_idx])
    }

    clinic_name <- trimws(clinic_name)

    # Store scraped data in data.frame
    page_df <- data.frame(clinic_name, clinic_address)

    return(page_df)
}

# Source URL
url <- "https://www.healthhub.sg/directory/clinics-and-polyclinics/"

# Instantiate a Selenium server
rD <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="91.0.4472.19")

# Assign the client to an object
rem_dr <- rD[["client"]]

# Navigate to the URL
rem_dr$navigate(url)

# Create a data.frame to store results
df <- data.frame()

# GET HTML of the first page of results in the directory
page <- read_html(rem_dr$getPageSource()[[1]])

# Store scraped data in temporary data.frame
temp_df <- scrape_clinics_data(page)

# Append temporary data.frame to main data.frame
df <- rbind(df, temp_df)

# Collect list of navigation links
links <- rem_dr$findElements(using = 'class', value = 'page-link')

# Retrieve number of results pages
results_pages <- c()
for (idx in 1:length(links)) {
    link_txt <- unlist(links[[idx]]$getElementText())
    if (!link_txt %in% c("", "❮", "❯")){
        if (length(str_split(link_txt, '/')[[1]]) > 1) {
            results_pages <- c(results_pages, str_split(link_txt, '/')[[1]][2])
        } else {
            results_pages <- c(results_pages, link_txt)
        }

    }
}

# Identify number of last results page
max_results_page <- max(as.numeric(results_pages))

# Move on to the second page of results
links[[length(links)]]$clickElement()

# Repeat the procedure from 2 to the maximum number of results pages, since we
# are already on the second page of results
for (i in 2:max_results_page) {
    page <- read_html(rem_dr$getPageSource()[[1]])

    temp_df <- scrape_clinics_data(page)

    df <- rbind(df, temp_df)

    if (i < max_results_page) {
        links <- rem_dr$findElements(using = 'class', value = 'page-link')
        links[[length(links)]]$clickElement()
    }
}

# Close the client and the server
rem_dr$close()
rD$server$stop()
```

If you are brand new to `Selenium`, I highly recommend you have a look at [this introductory guide](https://ivanmillanes.netlify.app/post/2020-06-30-webscraping-with-rselenium-and-rvest/) by Ivan Millanes and the additional resources they have linked there.

This is a simple implementation of the code. In any case, it's always good to think about the [ethics of web scraping](https://www.empiricaldata.org/dataladyblog/a-guide-to-ethical-web-scraping) first.